# Kaa - unable to create Configuration Schema with REST api

Tags: kaa

I was trying to create a configuration schema using the rest api provided. Im getting the following error while executing the given curl command. Please Help.
Sorry, I had to mask some info.

```
C:\xxxx>curl -v -S -u test:test123 -F'configuration
Schema={"applicationId":"32768","name":"Test configuration schema","description"
:"Configuration Schema Description"};type=application/json' -F file=@configurati
onschema.json "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/configurationSchema"
 | python -mjson.tool
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xxx.xx) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'test'
* WARNING: Using weak random seed
> POST /kaaAdmin/rest/api/configurationSchema HTTP/1.1
> Host: xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
> Authorization: Basic c3JlZTp0ZXN0MTIz
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 750
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------df9c304eed
a5285e
>
  0   750    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0*
Done waiting for 100-continue
} [407 bytes data]
100   750    0     0  100   750      0     46  0:00:16  0:00:16 --:--:--     0<
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 05:04:20 GMT
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1nlr86kwwgbv612ia314pqj68w;Path=/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Length: 321
< Server: Jetty(9.2.2.v20140723)
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
{ [321 bytes data]
100  1071  100   321  100   750     19     45  0:00:16  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using a different API. To upload a configuration schema you should use `/kaaAdmin/rest/api/saveConfigurationSchema`. Please see the API documentation [here](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/#!/Configuration/saveConfigurationSchema)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Previously Server REST API page was empty. So, I had to use [this link](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API). Now that I used the new API, It doesnt take the Configuration Schema .json file as parameter. Instead, it looks like I will have to create the tenant CTL first and used the CTL Schema ID for the Configuration Schema. However, now i get 403 for "create CTL Schema" though the tenant ID and Authenticated user are matching. Please help.

Comment: From the documentation, HTTP 403 is returned when _The authenticated user does not have the required role (TENANT_DEVELOPER or TENANT_USER) or the Tenant ID of the application does not match the Tenant ID of the authenticated user._ I have't tried much with the Kaa REST APIs. May I know why don't u try to do the same with the admin UI?

Comment: Im trying to configure my application through a script. I have used the UI to do it on one server, and its all working fine. Now I want to script the configuration of the application, and avoid the manual process. Im using python and requests module.

Comment: Im doing this to create CTL "        http://192.168.56.1:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/CTL/saveSchema?body={'namespace': 'org.hitachi.kaasample.schema', 'type': 'record', 'name': 'ConfigurationSchema', 'fields': [{'displayName': 'sample period', 'by_default': 1, 'type': 'int', 'name': 'sampleperiod'}]}&tenantId=1&applicationToken=49424475049782446707        ", Im using the Kaa sandbox. So, Tenant user is "admin/admin123" and tenantID is 1.

Comment: I think those credentials are of the TENANAT ADMIN.